# How to combine different pivot tables excel 2013

Tags: excel, pivot-table

What i have is three different pivot tables in one spreadsheet, each of these tables have a pivot chart linked to them, and the tables are all laid out like this:

Category|Count of id

What i want is to be able to add each row in each pivot table, to each corresponding row in the other table. For example...

In Cat1 pivot table, the first value is 111, the second value is 50.
In Cat2 pivot table, the first value is 77, the second value is 12.
In Cat3 pivot table, the first value is 17, the second value is 12.

What i want is to be able to add the first row in the Cat1 pivot table (111). To the first row in the Cat2 and Cat3 pivot table, same with the second and third etc...

So that eventually i will have one final table, with all of the values combined.

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to copy out the results of each Category into it's own tab and then create a final Pivot form that data.

Comment: As it stands your question might be good advise (I wouldn't know) but it looks a little meager. Would you mind updating your answering and adding in some more information, perhaps a small sample?